# Passing list to the parameters of a sqldatasource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have an arraylist in my code behind that stores the id values of various items that are within a database. Upon clicking a button, I wish to pass these id values to an SQLDataSource to act as a parameter for populating a gridview. Unfortunately, my limited knowledge of VB is hindering me, and I'm confused as to how one would go about doing such a thing.

*code behind*

```
Protected Sub Preview_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Preview_Button.Click

    Dim list As New ArrayList
    Dim atLeastOneRowSelected As Boolean = False
    'Iterate through the Devices.Rows property
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        'Access the CheckBox
        Dim cb As CheckBox = row.FindControl("DeviceSelector")
        If cb IsNot Nothing AndAlso cb.Checked Then
            atLeastOneRowSelected = True
            'First, get the device_id for the selected row
            Dim device_id As Integer = _
                Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value)
            list.Add(device_id)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

*SQLDataSource within .aspx page*

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LOTOConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [DEVICES] WHERE ([devices_id] = @devices_id)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="devices_id" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**EDIT**

After playing around a bit, I have realized that I can form my list into an appropriate SQL string using the join command. So the only portion that I am still not understanding is how to reference the SQLDataSource from my code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out what it was that I needed to do. I dynamically create an SQL query and pass that to my SQLDataSource. I'm not exactly sure if this makes me prone to SQL injection, but since the query I'm generating is pulling its data from a separate gridview, I believe that its alright?

*code behind*

```
Protected Sub Preview_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Preview_Button.Click

    'Finds all checkboxes that have been selected in GridView1
    Dim list As New ArrayList
    Dim atLeastOneRowSelected As Boolean = False

    'Iterate through each row of GridView1
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        'Access the CheckBox
        Dim cb As CheckBox = row.FindControl("DeviceSelector")
        If cb IsNot Nothing AndAlso cb.Checked Then
            atLeastOneRowSelected = True
            'Get the device_id of the selected row
            Dim device_id As Integer = _
                Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value)
            list.Add(device_id)
        End If
    Next

    If atLeastOneRowSelected Then
        'Generate an SQL command using the selected checkboxes
        Dim str As String = String.Join(" OR devices_id = ", list.ToArray())
        Dim query As String = "Select * FROM [DEVICES] where devices_id = " + str
        SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = query

        'Enable the GenerateReport Button
        GenerateReport_Button.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

*SQLDataSource*

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LOTOConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the SqlDataSource's Selecting event to set the value for parameter:`devices_id`. This event occurs just before the DataSource performs the Query. So any values set inside this event will be used by the query next to be executed.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server"     
     OnSelecting="SqlDataSource3_Selecting"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LOTOConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [DEVICES] WHERE ([devices_id] = @devices_id)">
```

I dont know the syntax in VB,  May be below example in C# may help you as the Logic is same, only syntax is different.

```
protected void SqlDataSource3_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e) 
 { 
   for (int i=0;i < arrList.Count - 1;i++)
    {
      // just for example suppose Business logic needs the First ID value
       if(i==0)
        {
         // the select parameters can be accessed using: e.Command.Parameters
         e.Command.Parameters["@devices_id"].Value == Convert.ToInt32(list[i]);
        }
     } 
  }
```